# Compare two different SOQL queries

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

[image]I am new to salesforce and I am stuck with a situation here.

I have a class which is scheduled every hour. I hit an account with the below code and an email is sent out to MAROPOST (Marketing automation tool). When this happen I want to track the Account and create a case or a log which says Welcome Email is sent so that I don't hit the same Account again.

Please help. Below is the working class. Please help

```
public class PD_WelcomeMaroPost {
public static string sendEmailThroughMaro(string myInpEmail) {
    string successContacts = '';
    string failureContacts = '';


    // SQL to fetch FBO who Joined Today
    list<Account> conts = new list<Account> ([SELECT name, Email_FLP_com__c,
    (SELECT Id
    FROM Stripe_Subscriptons__r
    WHERE Start_Date__c= TODAY
        AND Status__c='active'
        AND Welcome_Email__C = false
    LIMIT 1)
from account
where ID IN (
    select Distributor__c
    from Stripe_Subscripton__c
    where Start_Date__c= TODAY
        AND Status__c='active'
        AND Welcome_Email__C = false)
AND  Email_FLP_com__c != NULL
LIMIT 100]);



    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>' + conts);
    overallEmail myEmail = new overallEmail();
    List<Stripe_Subscripton__c> subsToUpdate = new List<Stripe_Subscripton__c>();
    for(Account c : conts){

        myEmail.email.campaign_id = 172;
        myEmail.email.contact.Email = c.Email_FLP_com__c;
        myEmail.email.contact.first_name = c.name;
        /**MAp<String, String> tags = new Map<String, String>();
        tags.put('firstName', c.name);
        myEmail.email.tags = tags;**/
        system.debug('#### Input JSON: ' + JSON.serialize(myEmail));


        try{
            String endpoint = 'http://api.maropost.com/accounts/1173/emails/deliver.json?auth_token=j-V4sx8ueUT7eKM8us_Cz5JqXBzoRrNS3p1lEZyPUPGcwWNoVNZpKQ';
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            req.setbody(JSON.serialize(myEmail));
            Http http = new Http();
            system.debug('Sending email');
            HTTPResponse response = http.send(req); 
            system.debug('sent email');
            string resultBodyGet = '';
            resultBodyGet = response.getBody();
            system.debug('Output response:' + resultBodyGet);
            maroResponse myMaroResponse = new maroResponse();
            myMaroResponse = (maroResponse) JSON.deserialize(resultBodyGet, maroResponse.class);
            system.debug('#### myMaroResponse: ' + myMaroResponse);
            if(myMaroResponse.message == 'Email was sent successfully')
               successContacts = successContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            else
                failureContacts = failureContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
        }
        catch (exception e) {
            failureContacts = failureContacts + ';' + c.Email_FLP_com__c;
            system.debug('#### Exception caught: ' + e.getMessage());                
        }

        c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0].Welcome_Email__c = true;
        subsToUpdate.add(c.Stripe_Subscriptons__r[0]);

    }
    Update subsToUpdate;
   return 'successContacts=' + successContacts + '---' + 'failureContacts=' + failureContacts;   

}

public class maroResponse {
    public string message {get;set;}
}

public class overallEmail {
    public emailJson email = new emailJson();
}

public class emailJson {
    public Integer campaign_id;
    public contactJson contact = new contactJson();
   // Public Map<String, String> tags;
}

public class contactJson {
    public string email;
    public string first_name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a callout in a loop, there's [governor limit of max 100 callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). See [Limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) to obtain current & max numbers programatically rather than hardcoding it.

Other than that it should be pretty simple change. First add your filter to the query and add a "subquery" (something like a JOIN) that pulls the related list of subscriptions

```java
list<Account> conts = new list<Account> ([SELECT name, Email_FLP_com__c,
        (SELECT Id
        FROM Stripe_Subscriptions__r
        WHERE Start_Date__c= TODAY
            AND Status__c='active'
            AND Welcome_Email__C = false
        LIMIT 1)
    from account
    where ID IN (
        select Distributor__c
        from Stripe_Subscripton__c
        where Start_Date__c= TODAY
            AND Status__c='active'
            AND Welcome_Email__C = false)
    AND  Email_FLP_com__c != NULL
    LIMIT 100]);
```

Then it's just few lines more

```java
List<Stripe_Subscription__c> subsToUpdate = new List<Stripe_Subscription__c>();

for(Account a : conts){
    // do your maropost code here

    a.Stripe_Subscriptions__r[0].Welcome_Email__c = true;
    subsToUpdate.add(a.Stripe_Subscriptions__r[0]);
}
update subsToUpdate;
```

Of course you might want to set that checkbox to true only if callout went OK ;)

Comment: I have updated with the logic you have suggested considering the limits but still I could not update the checkbox. And by the way thanks for helping. I get to learn so much from you

Comment: And what happens exactly? Does it throw an error at any point? Does it succesfully send the callouts but doesn't perform updates? Do you see anything suspicious in debug log? Maybe it doesn't find any Accounts that match conditions? Try with just 1 good account (hardcoded Id in the query) and comment out the try-catch, see what happens?

Comment: It throws no error... Query above runs, emails are sent our and we receive them. Tried one account too, just hard coded name email

Comment: And what does the debug log say about the update operation? does it run OK? What if you'd put `System.debug(subsToUpdate);` just before it? I'm running out of ideas, you might have a trigger or something that would be clearing this checkbox? What if you comment out pretty much everything related to callout from that function, leave only query, loop, setting the checkbox & the update call?

Comment: I have added System.debug(subsToUpdate); after Update and before update and to my surprise I don't find it in the log. I see there is no Trigger, No Workflow rule. I am surprised what is preventing me to update .

Comment: Are you sure it's correct method? maybe you're calling another one from VF with similar name(or different class ;)). Did your class save OK? Is there really no debug statement at all or maybe it outputs an empty list? Really clutching at straws here man...

Comment: I see I have scheduled to run this job every day and this is was the blocker for the field to be updated. As I have deleted the scheduled job the field is set to TRUE. Thanks for the help, you are truely sweet. I learn a lot of things from you

Comment: Ha, so it refused to save the class ;) thought it'd be something like that. It's SF's protection against accidental breaking of submitted jobs... If you want - you can bypass it: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_deploy_with_jobs.htm

Comment: Surprisingly this setting is enabled in my org. May be I wrote a wrong method to schedule this class. I think I should rewrite it and then check if this works

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code, I don't see where you tried to accomplish this. If you post your attempt I'd be glad to help fix it.

Instead I'll give you different logic for what you are trying to do.

```
1.) create new checkbox field
2.) in batch query where box is not checked
3.) send email
4.) check checkbox
```

to answer your comment here is some sample code, you will need to fix it yourself, i am just making temp names

```
for(sobjectname gg:[your query]){
Send email;
gg.checkbox = checked;
update gg;
}
```

it'd be better to make it bulkified though

```
list<yourSObject> tobeupdated = new list<yourSObject>([Your query]);

for(yourSObject gg: tobeupdated){
send email;
gg.checkbox = true;
}
update tobeupdated;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have created a check box on the Stripe_Subscripton__c object so that when I write this Query I say select Distributor__c from Stripe_Subscripton__c where Start_Date__c= TODAY AND Status__c='active' AND Welcome_Email__C = FALSE. Please help me change this Checkbox to TRUE when I send the email so that this particular record will not hit in my next iteration